# How to create a yii advanced console command that delete from database every 3 days

Tags: php, database, yii2, console, cron-task

In my database i have table name post and have column name day i want to create a **yii2 advanced console command** that delete posts older than 3 days can any one help me ?

Comment: You should include solutions you've tried in your question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is, create a Cron Job to delete the post older than 3 days

**Step 1:**  Create a controller inside your console/controllers directory as shown below

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\helpers\Console;

class CronController extends Controller {

    public function actionTest() {
        echo "Test cron job"; // your logic for deleting old post goes here
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Note:** `CronController` is the name of controller and action is `test`

**Step 2:** To run your cron job named `test` you need to have `yii` file inside your root directory. yii files code is shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/console/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/console/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/console/config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$exitCode = $application->run();
exit($exitCode);
```

**Note:** Make sure that you have all the necessary config files present inside your `console/config` directory.

**Step 3:** Now its time to run your cron job

Go to your root directory in command prompt/terminal and execute following command, and you must see the message echoed inside the test action.

```
 php yii cron/test
```

**Here**

1. cron => name of the controller
2. test => name of the action

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna give you an example of a command that I have for cleaning my database with the users that havent confirmed their email.

```
<?php
namespace app\commands;
use app\models\User;
use yii\console\Controller;

class LimpiarController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo User::deleteAll(['and', 'confirmed_at is null', ['>', '(current_timestamp - to_timestamp(created_at))', '24 hours']]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can tell me how to create that because this the first time i use this framework

Comment: Just create a TestController.php in the commands folder, write something like the code above but with a test (echo 'Hello'). Then go to the command line and in the root folder, where yii script is type './yii test', (make sure to name the controller like TestController), you should now see Hello in your bash.

Comment: it's not work i create <?php
namespace app\commands;
use app\models\User;
use yii\console\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
} but i get error when run command

Comment: what error do you get? Be more specific. By the way you dont need to use app\models\User.

Comment: Go to the Root directory of your project, where all the folders are and type `./yii`, you should see commands in yellow like migrate, message... There should be the command test too. Do you get them?

Comment: i send you in email im not get test get migrate message ..... but no test